# SimpleXML Namespace or SemiColin

Tags: php, xml

Im having a problem getting a namespaced (Or semi-colin') item with PHP's SimpleXML. I've done a little digging through google and tried the likes if asXML but im back at square one.

**The part I can't get < content:encoded >**

```
http://content.sportsdatallc.com/?feed=rss2&cat=364
```

**PHP**

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
print_r($xml);
```

I can get all the nodes that I need, except for that piece above. If i print_r it doesnt showup.

**I have also tried this:**

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item)
{
    echo 11;
    $art = $item->children('content:encoded');
    print_r($art);
}
```

Comment: I have this resolved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397734/regex-for-colon-in-an-xml-tag-when-parsing-fails-with-php-and-simplexml-load-str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution str_replace the content:encoded with content.

```
$xml = str_replace('content:encoded>', 'content>', $xml);
```

It may not be the best solution but it is simple and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
foreach($xml->channel->item as $item) {
  $contentNodes = $item->children('content',true);
   ...
}
```

Take a look at namespaces for this class.

Comment: Does it work for you with the ",true" added?  I missed it out *apologies*.